# Error while custom Form creation in drupal8

Tags: 8, forms

I am trying to create a custom form in Drupal-8, by refering online docs. But I am facing one error, not able to find out what is the wrong am doing here, please find below code and error.

Error: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Dupal\amazing_forms\Formss\ContributeForm in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal8\modules\custom\amazing_forms\src\Formss\ContributeForm.php on line 46`

Folder structure:

```
modules->custom->amazing_forms
                   ->amazing_forms.info.yml
                   ->amazing_forms.routing.yml
                   ->src  
                       ->Formss
                          ->ContributeForm.php
```

Code:
**amazing_forms.routing.yml**

```
amazing_forms_contribute:
  path: 'amazing_forms/contribute'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Registration Page'
    _form: '\Drupal\amazing_forms\Formss\ContributeForm'
  requirements: 
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**ContributeForm.php**

```
<?php
namespace Dupal\amazing_forms\Formss;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class ContributeForm extends FormBase {
  /**
     *{@inheritdoc}
     */

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'amazing_forms_contribute_form';
  }


  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['title'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Title'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['video'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Youtube video'),
    );
    $form['develop'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('I would like to be involved in developing this material'),
    );
    $form['description'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => t('Description'),
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
      drupal_set_message($key . ': ' . $value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to rename the class name in the routing.yml and in the ContributeForm? Sometimes it's just a caching black magic

Comment: The namespace **Fromss** is quite unusual, but if you use it consistently it should work. What is not working is **Dupal** in the namespace.

Comment: @ LamaDelRay I tried by changing the class name.. but not success. While clearing cache only i am getting this error.

Comment: Yes fix the typos, clear cache and try again.

Comment: Check the folder where the form class file is. You can have two identical form files there. It can happen for example when you create a form using drupal console and that process is interrupted by some error.

Comment: May i know when this error will come: InvalidArgumentException: Class "\Drupal\amazing_forms\Formss\ContriForm" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver->getInstanceFromDefinition() (line 29 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver.php).

Comment: @Suraj As alrdy pointed out. `namespace Dupal\amazing_forms\Formss;` should be `Drupal` you missed the **r**, did u fix this? and cleared the cache?

Comment: @No Sssweat Now I did that, and it worked. Thanks for noting about spelling mistake.